# Async/await & promise to wait for a post request to complete and get what was added does not work

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

So, when I create a new user, it is added to the database, and after that I want to receive the list of updated users. But even waiting for the finalization of the post method to happen, the new user that has just been created is never returned, only after the creation of a new user does the fetch return the one that was previously created.

I tried this:

```
createUser()
    async function createUser(){
        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3334/user", {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify({
              name: name,
              password: password,
              email: email,
            }),
            headers: {
              "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
            },
          })
          const data = await response.json()
          console.log(data)

          const fetchResponse = await fetch("http://localhost:3334/users")
          const fetchData = await fetchResponse.json()
          
          console.log(fetchData)
          
    }
```

And this:

```
    fetch("http://localhost:3334/user", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name: name,
        password: password,
        email: email,
      }),
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
      },
    }).then((response) => {
      if (response.status === 200) {
        return fetch("http://localhost:3334/users")
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((data) => console.log(data));
      }
    });
```

I expect that the user that I just created, appear in the GET method.

This is /user endpoint using express:

```
router.post('/user', (req, res) => {
    res.json({requestBody: req.body})
    bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, saltRounds, function(err, hash) {
        db.query("INSERT INTO users (email, name, password) VALUES (?,?,?)", [req.body.email, req.body.name, hash], function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("Result: " + JSON.stringify(result));
      })
    
    });
})
```

Comment: Does the `/user` endpoint only return a response once the user has been created? Might help if you share what occurs when `/user` is hit

Comment: @NickParsons Sorry about that, I edited my question to include the endpoint. And since you said that, means that I have to wait until the query is finished right?

Comment: Yeah, so try moving the `res.json()` call after the `console.log("Result: " ....)` which is when your query/insert would have completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your `/user` endpoint is returning a response before you've inserted the new user. You should return your response when the user was inserted or if an error occurs, eg:

```js
router.post('/user', (req, res) => {
  bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, saltRounds, function(err, hash) {
    db.query("INSERT INTO users (email, name, password) VALUES (?,?,?)", [req.body.email, req.body.name, hash], function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).end(err.message);
      } else {
        res.json({requestBody: req.body})
      }
    });
  });
})
```